# Putting two flexslider side-by-side?

Tags: html, css, flexslider

I'm having trouble putting two flexsliders side by side.
Here's my code:

```
<div class="flexslider" style="width:50%;height:50%;position:relative;">
  <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="img1.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img2.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img3.jpg" />
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="flexslider" style="width:50%;height:50%;position:relative;">
  <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="img1.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img2.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img3.jpg" />
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I think it could be solved by adding float:left somewhere in the CSS code, but I honestly don't know where.

Comment: `.flexslider { float: left; }`

Comment: No,this doens't seem to work either... I wonder if the problem is laying somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your html and css with this.

```css
.flexslider{
    display:inline-block;
    width:49%; 
  }
```

```html
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="img1.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img2.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img3.jpg" />
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="img1.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img2.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img3.jpg" />
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks,but this doesn't seem to work for me. i edited my flexslider.css like this:

'.flexslider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display:inline-block;
}'

Comment: also give the width as 49%

Comment: Here's something weird:if I add  width:49%  in the CSS file and use the class in HTML file,it seems to ingore that parameter and just use 100% of the space. If I add width:49%; as a style parameter in the div,it actually works. Thanks anyway friend,it works now.